# Working on my dissertation, and need to figure out whether to use MANOVA, MANCOVA, Multiple regression, or multivariate regression

Tags: regression, manova, mancova

I am working on my dissertation, and I am having a hard time choosing a statistical model to follow.  I am using an existing dataset. The results of the dataset are self-reported. There are more than 30 samples so I can consider the scores normally distributable.

My dependent variables are the Consciousness of Self variable (which includes answers on a five point likert scale, Strongly Agree to Strongly Disagree).  And, my second dependent variable is called Internal Moral Perspective and is a conglomeration of three different areas of a test, one with a 4 point likert scale, two with five point likert scales (but their may or may not be a conglomerate score already done in the dataset).

My independent variable is fraternity affiliation versus non-fraternity affiliated students.

My covariates are sexuality (gay/bisexual/questioning v. straight), race/ethnicity (8 categorical variables), and first generation college student (first gen v. not first gen).

I am considering using either a multivariate regression analysis, a MANOVA, a MANCOVA, or a multiple regression.  Not sure which to use.  I want to basically find out if fraternity men in those categories outperform on the DV measures than non-fraternity men.

Any help or even a nudge in the right direction would be graciously appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to add.  One more covariate...categorical (institution undergrad population) defined as small, medium, or large

Comment: If I were in your position I would not want to choose a test until I had established the psychometric properties (validity and reliability, each assessed ideally in multiple ways) of your dependent variables.  Also, "more than 30" is cryptic:  what is N?  And as you may realize, there is much more to satisfying assumptions of these procedures than simply having N > 30.

Answer (score 2):

I have not clearly understood your variables. I believe you have one continuous response variable and more than one continuous predictor variables.

If it is the case, you need **multiple regression**. But make sure to check for the assumption.
For dealing with categorical predictors, you can use **dummy (indicator variables)**.

Also, **ANCOVA (analysis of co-variance)** can be performed. The results would be same.

The relation between multiple regression with dummy variables and ANCOVA is similar to that of between simple regression with dummy variables and ANOVA.

To get continuous variables (factors) from likert scale questionnair, factor analysis can be used.

If you have literature support for the factors, go for CFA (confirmatory factor analysis). Else, EFA can be performed (exploratory factor analysis).

Edit: Thanks @ Silverfish. Somehow, I missed it.
So, in case of multiple response and multiple predictors, it becomes multivarite multiple regression. Hence, MANCOVA (multivariate analysis of co-variance) can be used.
But surely, it depends on what you want to do?

Comment: "I have not clearly understood your variables. I believe you have one continuous response variable and more than one continuous predictor variables." - the OP lists two DVs, consciousness of self and internal moral perspective. But it seems the OP wants to consider them individually, in which case treating this as one DV with several IVs seems ok.